# Can onedrive for business client show files without syncing them

Tags: onedrive-for-business, synchronisation

I'm thinking of a network file share. If I have a file on SharePoint can the desktop client show me that file, but not sync it to the machine?

Am I the only one confused by onedrive for business?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case you are wanting the Windows Explorer view, right now OD4B does bidirectional synchronization. The explorer view is more of the network file share you are thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your OneDrive for Business to a network drive on your computer. In this setup the files will not be synced. It works in much the same way as if you had mapped a network drive to a local file server. Microsoft have a guide and troubleshooting tips on mapping a network drive to OneDrive for Business here: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2616712

Zee Drive, a commercial tool, also provides a means to map network drives to OneDrive for Business and will make the drives permanent so they are available to you on signing in to Windows: [Map OneDrive for Business to a network drive with Zee Drive](http://www.thinkscape.com/Map-Network-Drives-To-Office-365-OneDrive/)

Disclosure; Zee Drive is a tool my company develops.